# How to solve the error "Nonetype object has no attribute 'bind' "?

Tags: python, kivy

I just started out creating a new app in kivy and I simply don't realise why it's giving me an error, when trying to call the StringProperty kujund from the app class.

Python:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.clock import Clock

kv = Builder.load_file("autogeo.kv")
kujund = "null"

class autogeo(App):
    manager = ScreenManager()

    Screen1 = Screen(name="esimene")
    Screen2 = Screen(name='teine')
    Screen3 = Screen(name="kolmas")
    Screen4 = Screen(name='neljas')
    Screen5 = Screen(name="viies")
    kujund = StringProperty()

    def update(self, *args):
        pass
    def build(self):
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 0.1)
        return kv

if __name__ == "__main__":
    autogeo().run()
```

Kv:

```
ScreenManager:
    id: manager
    size: root.width, root.height

    Screen:
        name: "esimene"
        GridLayout:
            cols: 2
            rows: 3
            Button:
                text: "ruut"
                on_press:
                    manager.current = "teine"
                    manager.transition.direction ="left"
                    app.kujund: "ruut"

            Button:
                text: "ristkylik"
                on_press:
                    manager.current = "teine"
                    manager.transition.direction ="left"
            Button:
                text: "kolmnurk"
                on_press:
                    manager.current = "teine"
                    manager.transition.direction ="left"
            Button:
                text: "taisnurkne kolmnurk"
                on_press:
                    manager.current = "teine"
                    manager.transition.direction ="left"
            Button:
                text: "ring"
                on_press:
                    manager.current = "teine"
                    manager.transition.direction ="left"
            Button:
                text: "vordhaarne trapets"
                on_press:
                    manager.current = "teine"
                    manager.transition.direction ="left"
    Screen:
        name: "teine"
        FloatLayout:
            Label:
                text: "Valisid kujundi " + app.kujund
                font_size: self.width * 0.1
            Button:
                text: "tagasi"
                size_hint: 1, 0.2
                on_press:
                    manager.current = "esimene"
                    manager.transition.direction = "right"
```

Traceback:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\ricsi\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 249, in create_handler
     return eval(value, idmap), bound_list
   File "C:\Users\ricsi\PycharmProjects\ToolsforMaths\autogeo.kv", line 46, in <module>
     text: "Valisid kujundi " + app.kujund
   File "C:\Users\ricsi\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\parser.py", line 75, in __getattribute__
     object.__getattribute__(self, '_ensure_app')()
   File "C:\Users\ricsi\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\parser.py", line 70, in _ensure_app
     app.bind(on_stop=lambda instance:
 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bind'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are loading a .kv that uses "app" before creating "app" so there is None throwing that error. The solution is to parse it after creating the "app", for example the build method.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.clock import Clock


class autogeo(App):
    manager = ScreenManager()

    Screen1 = Screen(name="esimene")
    Screen2 = Screen(name="teine")
    Screen3 = Screen(name="kolmas")
    Screen4 = Screen(name="neljas")
    Screen5 = Screen(name="viies")
    kujund = StringProperty()

    def update(self, *args):
        pass

    def build(self):
        kv = Builder.load_file("autogeo.kv")
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 0.1)
        return kv


if __name__ == "__main__":
    autogeo().run()
```

Comment: Since the 'kv` file is correctly named, you can eliminate the call to `Builder.load_file()` completely.